# PHP check if object can be converted to integer?

Tags: php, int, type-conversion

In PHP, it seems like every object can be converted to an integer, just by calling `intval($object)`, but this is not what I want. What I want is, to check if the object would be valid to be converted into an integer for what a human thinks it is.

I.e., valid objects would be

- `12`
- `12.0`
- `"12"`
- `"12.0"`

And not valid would be

- `MyFooInstance()`
- `"some string"`
- `"12.0.0"`
- `"0 12.0"`

etc.
In python, I could simply to the following:

```
try:
    int(var)
except (TypeError, ValueError):
    return False
return True
```

How can I achive this in PHP?

Comment: [The behaviour of converting **objects** to integer is undefined.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting)

Comment: Go with Dogbert and refer Gordon

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php).

```
<?php
$tests = array(
    "42", 
    1337, 
    "1e4", 
    "not numeric", 
    array(), 
    9.1
);

foreach ($tests as $element) {
    if (is_numeric($element)) {
        echo "'{$element}' is numeric", PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo "'{$element}' is NOT numeric", PHP_EOL;
    }
}
?>


'42' is numeric
'1337' is numeric
'1e4' is numeric
'not numeric' is NOT numeric
'Array' is NOT numeric
'9.1' is numeric
```

(From the page)

Comment: Thank you, must have missed that!

Answer (score 6):

**Integer** (not just numeric) test: 
http://codepad.org/3E8IYHKY

```
function to_int_or_null( $v ){
  if( is_int(     $v ))  return $v; 
  if( is_float(   $v ))  return $v === (float)(int)$v  ?  (int)$v  :  null;
  if( is_numeric( $v ))  return to_int_or_null( +$v );
  return null;
}
```

Results:

```
int(1)                                  int(1)
float(1)                                int(1)
float(-0)                               int(0)
string(2) "-1"                          int(-1)
string(2) "+1"                          int(1)
string(1) "1"                           int(1)
string(2) " 1"                          int(1)
string(2) "01"                          int(1)
string(3) " 01"                         int(1)
string(4) " -01"                        int(-1)
string(3) "1e0"                         int(1)
string(4) "1.00"                        int(1)
string(18) "1.0000000000000001"         int(1)
string(18) "0.0000000000000001"         NULL
string(17) "1.000000000000001"          NULL
string(4) "1.11"                        NULL
string(4) "1e40"                        NULL
string(6) "1e9999"                      NULL
float(1.1100000000000000977)            NULL
float(1.0000000000000000304E+40)        NULL
float(INF)                              NULL
string(4) "0xFF"                        NULL or int(255) !!!
string(6) "0b1111"                      NULL
string(5) "123  "                       NULL
string(0) ""                            NULL
string(2) "  "                          NULL
string(6) "123foo"                      NULL
string(6) "foo456"                      NULL
string(3) "foo"                         NULL
bool(true)                              NULL
bool(false)                             NULL
NULL                                    NULL
array(0) {}                             NULL
object(stdClass)#7 (0) {}               NULL
```

**Old, buggy answer**
http://codepad.org/LoqfAgNl
Fails with integer-valued float type: `(double)123`

```
function is_integerable( $v ){
  return is_numeric($v) && +$v === (int)(+$v);
}
```

Comment: Thank you ver much, but `is_numeric` fits too. :)

Answer (score 4):

See PHP's [ctype_digit()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php).

This function evaluates a string to see if all character are numeric. Thus `"1.1"` will not return `true` because `"."` is not numeric, but `"11"` will. Also note this works for strings only, so numbers without the surrounding quotation marks will also not work.

Answer (score -1):

check out `is_numeric($var)`: http://php.net/is_numeric

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
if((int)$variable) {...
```

Comment: The condition in `if( (int)$variable )` would evaluate to `false` when `$variable == 0`.

Comment: yep, forgot that "little" detail :)